# Flutter application only shows blank page in debug mode, but runs with "flutter run" command

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble debugging a Flutter application. When I run the application in debug mode with the F5 key, only a blank page is displayed and there are no errors or warnings. However, when I run the "flutter run" command, the application runs correctly. This problem occurs in both Visual Studio Code and Android Studio, and on both emulators and real devices. I even tried testing on Linux, but still encountered the same blank page issue. This problem occurs with all the applications I have created, including ones that worked correctly a week ago. I even created a new raw project, but it still had the same problem.

I have tried changing all SDKs, installing and testing different versions of Flutter and Dart, uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio Code, but the problem remains. Additionally, tools that work correctly on another system do not work on my Ubuntu operating system. I have included the output of the "flutter doctor" command below. Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

**launch.json file:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MY_APP",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "MY_APP (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "MY_APP (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        }
    ]
}
```

**flutter Doctor :**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on Ubuntu 23.04 6.2.0-20-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc5)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    ✗ clang++ is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install clang), or can be downloaded from
      https://releases.llvm.org/
    ✗ CMake is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install cmake), or can be downloaded from
      https://cmake.org/download/
    ✗ ninja is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install ninja-build), or can be downloaded from
      https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
    ✗ pkg-config is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install pkg-config), or can be downloaded from
      https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code
[!] Proxy Configuration
    ! NO_PROXY is not set
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had manipulated my system files, and as you can see in the output of **`flutter doctor`** command, there is a problem of accessing the Internet.
I suggest that if you make a change at the operating system level, do a general review.
in my case, the problem was solved by emptying the contents of the **`/etc/environment`** file, which I had changed before.